# make remove .cc after building .so without control

Tags: makefile, cython

Recently I encountered an extremly strange behavior of `Makefile`:

In current dir, I have `hello.pyx`:

```
#cython: language_level=3

print("Hello, world!")
```

and in `..` I have `Makefile`:

```
includes=$(shell python3 -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('include'))")
CFLAGS=-shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -Oz -flto -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I$(includes)
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-plugin-opt=O2

%.cc: %.pyx
        cython --cplus $< -o $@

%.so: %.cc
        clang++ ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS} $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f *.cc *.so

.PHONY: clean
```

When I build `hello.so` in current dir using `make -f ../Makefile hello.so`, it deletes `.cc` after building `.so`:

```
cython --cplus hello.pyx -o hello.cc
clang++ -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -Oz -flto -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python3.7m -Wl,-plugin-opt=O2 hello.cc -o hello.so
rm hello.cc
```

I tried remove target `.PHONY` and `clean`, but it doesn't help.

How can I stop `make` from `rm hello.cc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file is considered an [intermediate file](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html).  All you have to do to keep it from being removed is mention it as a target or prerequisite anywhere in the makefile, like this:

```
sources: $(patsubst %.so,%.cc,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
```